# How to enable or disable value inside combobox with javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to `enable/disable` value inside `<select> tag` based on value from PHP.

The variable is `$gender.`

> If $gender = female then value(Menstruasi) = enabled
>
> else if $gender = male then value(Menstruasi) = disabled

Here is the code :

```
<select name = "keterangan_cuti_khusus">
<option value="" selected> - = - </option>
<option value="Insidental">Insidental</option>
<option value="Pengembangan_skill">Pengembangan Skill</option>
<option value="Ibadah_Haji">Ibadah Haji</option>
<option value="Masa_kerja">Masa Kerja</option>
<option value="Melahirkan">Melahirkan</option>
<option value="mensturasi">Mensturasi</option>  
</select>
```

I want

```
<option value="mensturasi">Mensturasi</option>  <--- disable/enable -->
```

change where gender is female or male.

Is there any ideas ?

Comment: a simple if\else then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <option value="mensturasi" <?php if($gender=='male') { echo 'disabled'; } ?>>Mensturasi</option>
```